# want to reset only the last newly inserted dynamically block on the click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var qBlock='<form id="resetblock"><div class="newqandaBlock"><div class="input-group margin-bottom-20"><span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question Asked "><button type="button" class="btn btn-purple closequest" style="position: absolute;top: 3px;"><span> <i class="fa  fa-close"></i></span></button></div> <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20"> <span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></span><textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="info" placeholder="Your Answer"></textarea> </div><div class="input-group margin-bottom-20"><span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></span><textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="info"  placeholder="Add Your Comments"></textarea> </div></div></form>';
  
$("#addQuestion").on("click",function(){        
     $(qBlock).insertAfter(".qandaBlock");
});

$("#resetblock").on("click",'.closequest',  function(){ 
     alert("Do you really want to remove the question?!?");     
     $(this).closest(".newqandaBlock").remove();        
});

$("#resetblock").on("click",'.resetlatest',  function(){ 
     alert("Do you really want to reset the question?!?");     
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="resetblock" name="resetblock" > 
                                             <div class="qandaBlock"> 
             <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question Asked ">
           </div>
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></span>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="info" placeholder="Your Answer"></textarea> 
              </div>
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
           <span class="input-group-addon purple"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></span>
           <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="info" placeholder="Add Your Comments"></textarea> </div>
           </div>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default resetlatest" id="resetlatest" ">Reset</button>&nbsp;
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-purple" id="addQuestion"><i class="fa  fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Add Another Question</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above line of code will reset the whole form. But , How to reset only the last newly inserted block of question , answer and comment. I dont want on the click of the reset button, the whole form to be reset. I only want to reset the last newly inserted block to be clear its fields with blanks on the click of reset button.

Comment: You are duplicating your `<form>` ID. **IDs must be unique** in a HTML document. Based on your code, you will be nesting `<form>` within a `<form>` (per iteration/click). Also, your code snippet doesn't seem to be working—please check if (1) jQuery is actually loaded, (2) you are appending event handlers on DOM ready and (3) there are any error messages in console.

Comment: Now check @Terry, someone edited thatone, what i acual posted. Now its running. But I want to reset only the last newly inserted block's fields to be clear on the click of reset , not all or not of the previous ones.

Comment: @Pooja all you've done is rolled it back to your **awful** markup. The edit simply tidied up your code so it was remotely readable. Terry's comment still stands, your code is inserting a duplicate ID, and not only that it's nesting it within the other.

Answer (score 0):

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/25/

to achieve getting the last or newly inserted element, i used jquery's :last-child selector as seen below.

its also better (and more maintainable) to use .clone() than it is to build html with javascript if you have a template.

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="template" class="section">
        <input class="question" type="text" />
        <br/>
        <textarea class="answer"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <textarea class="comments"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="reset" style="margin-right:10px;">Reset Last Question</a>
<a href="#" class="add">Add Another Question</a>

$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
    clone.find('.question').val('');
    clone.find('.answer').val('');
    clone.find('.comments').val('');
    clone.appendTo('.content');
});

$('.reset').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.section').length);
    var last = $('.content .section:last-child');
    last.find('.question').val('');
    last.find('.answer').val('');
    last.find('.comments').val('');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to change, other than the sh**ty markup:

1) Stop the forms from nesting each other and put the new form at the bottom after other forms:

```
$("#addQuestion").on("click",function(){        
     $(qBlock).insertAfter(".qandaBlock");
});
```

to

```
$("#addQuestion").on("click",function(){        
     $('body').append(qBlock); // Append the form to the body, so it will sit after the last form
});
```

2) Remove all `id="resetblock"`, from markup and from the JS

3) Change all `$("#resetblock").on("click"` to `$(document).on("click"`

4) Change the `alert`'s to `confirm`'s:

```
var blnReset = confirm("Do you want to reset the question?");
if (blnReset == true) {
   //Reset the question
}
```